# Compare two image variables in pygame

Tags: python

I have this method that when called it changes the weapon for the player, I want to somehow be able to determine if the current weapon is already the new weapon. I tried with `is` and `pygame.surface.get_at()` but it didn't work. Eventually I will do another action when the weapon is the same, the print statement is there just for now to check if it works.

```
class BulletsManager:
    """The BulletsManager class manages the player bullets."""
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
        self.thunder_weapon = pygame.image.load(WEAPONS['thunderbolt'])
        self.fire_weapon = pygame.image.load(WEAPONS['firebird'])

    def change_weapon(self, player, weapon_name):
        """Change the player weapon."""
        if player == "thunderbird":
            new_weapon = pygame.image.load(WEAPONS[weapon_name])
            if new_weapon == self.thunder_weapon:
                print('New weapon is the same as the current one')
            else:
                self.thunder_weapon = new_weapon
        elif player == "phoenix":
            self.fire_weapon = pygame.image.load(WEAPONS[weapon_name])
```

Comment: You change the image so you know the weapon. Store the name of the weapon in an attribute.

Comment: `pygame.surface.get_at()` is a very time consuming operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to solve the problem:

```
class BulletsManager:
    """The BulletsManager class manages the player bullets."""
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
        self.thunder_weapon = pygame.image.load(WEAPONS['thunderbolt'])
        self.current_thunder_weapon = 'thunderbolt'

        self.fire_weapon = pygame.image.load(WEAPONS['firebird'])
        self.current_fire_weapon = 'firebird'

    def set_weapon(self, player, weapon_name):
        """Change the player weapon."""
        if player == "thunderbird":
            if weapon_name == self.current_thunder_weapon:
                print('New weapon is the same as the current one. - thunder')
            else:
                self.thunder_weapon = pygame.image.load(WEAPONS[weapon_name])
                self.current_thunder_weapon = weapon_name
        elif player == "phoenix":
            if weapon_name == self.current_fire_weapon:
                print("New weapon ins the same as the current one - fire")
            else:
                self.fire_weapon = pygame.image.load(WEAPONS[weapon_name])
                self.current_fire_weapon = weapon_name
```

Or using a dictionary:

```
class BulletsManager:
    """The BulletsManager class manages the player bullets."""
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
        self.weapons = {
            "thunderbird": {
                "weapon": pygame.image.load(WEAPONS['thunderbolt']),
                "current": "thunderbolt"
            },
            "phoenix": {
                "weapon": pygame.image.load(WEAPONS["firebird"]),
                "current": "firebird"
            }
        }

    def set_weapon(self, player, weapon_name):
    """Change the player weapon."""
    if weapon := self.weapons.get(player):
        if weapon_name == weapon["current"]:
            print('New weapon is the same as the current one.')
        else:
            weapon["weapon"] = pygame.image.load(WEAPONS[weapon_name])
            weapon["current"] = weapon_name
```